# firstAppear won't work, ViewController init every time

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Bool firstAppear in my SecondViewController. When a video is played the Bool becomes false. Then if I go back to my FirstViewController and return , the video plays again. As I understand I always create another instance of the ViewController so thats why my logic is false. What are the changes I need to make to achieve it?

```
@IBAction func nextButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let secondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("answer") as? SecondViewController{    
             SecondViewController.id = self.id  
        }   
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
}
```

And in Second:

```
private var firstAppear = true

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if firstAppear {
            do {
                try playVideo()
                firstAppear = false
            } catch AppError.InvalidResource(let name, let type) {
                debugPrint("Could not find resource \(name).\(type)")
            } catch {
                debugPrint("Generic error")
            }

        }
    }
@IBAction func pop(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `firstAppear` to be shared by all instances of this class, then you need to make it `static`:

```
private static var firstAppear = true

...
    if SecondViewController.firstAppear {
...
            SecondViewController.firstAppear = false
```

Static variables are associated with the type, not any particular instance.

Keep in mind that static variables are still in-memory variables. They don't persist between executions of the program. This will likely lead to confusion and cause `playVideo()` to be executed somewhat randomly (once per program launch, but "program launch" is not something the user has real visibility into).

In most cases what you really meant here was to store a persistent variable, and that's usually done with `NSUserDefaults`. Something like this:

```
private let hasAppearedKey = "hasAppeared"

private var hasAppearedKey {
    get { return NSUserDefaults().boolForKey(hasAppearedKey) }
    set { NSUserDefaults().setBool(newValue, forKey(hasAppearedKey) }
}

...

if !hasAppeared { ... }
```

This will persist until the user uninstalls the app. The reason I've inverted the meaning of the bool is because an unset bool is false. This simplifies things a little bit (otherwise you'd have to use registerDefaults to make the default true instead.)

Note that this is not a `static` variable. It doesn't really matter one way or the other, because all instances share the same defaults database.

Comment: ok but , should I make more instances of the same screen ? Is this the correct way to go ?

Comment: Generally you shouldn't be calling `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. You should use a Storyboard segue. But that's going to create multiple instances, too. View controllers should never expect to exist if they are not currently onscreen. (See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardSegue.html for segues.)